# Resource not found when showing a web dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an asp page that has a button in it. And once the button is clicked, it should display a web dialog which is placed on another folder on a same solution. Unfortunately, when that button is clicked it displays an error saying that the resource could not be found. I have validated the path where it is and the page that I am trying to access is there. I am using javascript to open up the web dialog. Here is the code I use:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        var w;
        function openWindow(lot, spec, specname, ID) {
            var myArguments = new Object();
            myArguments.param1 = 'popUp';

            w = window.showModalDialog("WebForms/MAXIMDataCollection/WaferSortCSP/CSPTesterSummary.aspx?lotID=" + lot + "&specID=" + spec + "&specname=" + specname + "&ID=" + ID, myArguments, 'dialogHeight: 650px; dialogWidth: 1050px; edge: Sunken; center: Yes; help: No; status=1;resizable=0; Yes; scroll:0;');

        }
    </script>
```

Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: Can you look at the dev tools in your browser and see what is the actual request being placed from `window.showModalDialog`? See if that matches the URL of your page. Try to paste that in another browser window and see if you get the page you're expecting, or an error.

Comment: Hi Floremin, can you teach me how to do that one?

Comment: I'm sure you can search and find instructions for your particular browser.

Comment: You do know that w has global scope (window.w)? If you only need this variable in your function you should change it to var w = .... Even if you do need it somewhere else it's not a good idea to just scope it globally, at the very least wrap it in a variable: window.myApplication={};window.myApplication.w=window.showModal....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you open it in Firefox or chrome with the following changes to the javascript code; then press F12 and check out the console?

```
    var w;
    function openWindow(lot, spec, specname, ID) {
        var myArguments = new Object();
        myArguments.param1 = 'popUp';
        console.log("WebForms/MAXIMDataCollection/WaferSortCSP/CSPTesterSummary.aspx?lotID=" + 
         lot + "&specID=" + spec + "&specname=" + specname + "&ID=" + ID
        w = window.showModalDialog("WebForms/MAXIMDataCollection/WaferSortCSP/CSPTesterSummary.aspx?lotID=" 
          + lot + "&specID=" + spec + "&specname=" + specname + "&ID=" + 
          ID, myArguments, 'dialogHeight: 650px; dialogWidth: 1050px; edge: Sunken; center: Yes; help: No; status=1;resizable=0; Yes; scroll:0;');
    }
```

Then try to open the url that's logged and see what parameter or url is wrong. The url is a relative url from current page so if you're at: localhost/subfolder/mypage.aspx you should open localhost/subfolder/WebForms/MAXIMD... If you want to open a page from root (is a better idea if you're using it on multiple pages in multiple sub folders) then change the JavaScript code to open a URL from root level:

```
        w = window.showModalDialog("/WebForms/MAX...
```

Now it'll open localhost/WebForms/... no matter from what subfolder you run the script.

Comment: Hey HMR! Your solution works great. Thank you. Any chance on explaining why do I need to add another '/' at the string? Cheers!

Comment: not having / in the start is relative to current position so if you're in localhost/subFolder/mypage then "somefile.aspx" will take you to localhost.subFolder/somefile.aspx but "/somefile.asxp" will take you to the root (is localhost) so to localhost/somefile.aspx. If you're in localhost/sub1/sub2/hello.html then a link to "../somefile.aspx" will take you to localhost/sub1/somefile.axpx because "../" means one directory up from whereever you are now.